# Where is the 'toaster' easter egg?

Tags: gears-of-war-2

Where can I find the gears of war 2 toaster easter egg? 
I heard there was one but I never found out where to find it.

I almost had the achievement but never got around to find that one.

Comment: I like em' crispy on the outside!

Answer (score 7):

Summarized from [this page](http://www.eeggs.com/items/54356.html):

The level is "The best laid plans", right before you get to the long stairway down to the lower palace.
At the top of the stairs there is a sort of platform with a decorative block at the edge, on the side towards the stairs. Break the block, there will be a toaster with steel plated bread inside.
Push the bread in, the toaster will start to smoke, and Marcus will cough. The toast will pop up and Marcus (if thats who pushes the button)will shout "Who wants toast?" If anyone is near, they might shout "I like 'em crispy."
The higher difficulty you're playing on, the more dialog you'll get from Dom & Marcus.

If you like to find easter eggs I suggest you to bookmark the site I linked, it's a great resource.

Comment: Can you put the relevant parts of that link into your answer?

Comment: @DerpyHooves done